# Java - Stop thread while consumer is waiting and tomcat is shutdown

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, thread-safety

I have a servlet, and it is a singleton.

In the init, I create the producer and the consumers.

```
consumer = new MyThread();
consumer.start();
```

and the method run is like this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (!isShutdown()) {
        if (queue.isEmpty())
            queue.wait();
        else
            ...
    }
}
```

then i have the destroy method. 
that set shutdown to true and I use .join

```
        consumer.setShutdown(true); 
        consumer.join();
```

but the method .join got lock.. and never finishes.
If I change the queue.wait to Thread.sleep(), it works... but I don't want to change... what I'm doing wrong?

if I don't finish the thread, I got it:
SEVERE: The web application [/test] appears to have started a thread named [Comsumer0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using wait/notify methods is the old way to create a Consumer-Producer pattern.

It is better to use BlockingQueue.

`BlockingQueue.put()` - for Producer, and `BlockingQueue.poll()` - for Consumer.

BlockingQueue hides wait method underneath `BlockingQueue.poll`, `BlockingQueue.put` and will block a Consumer thread until Producer adds value to queue.

To fix the example above, you should make it wait for a finite amount of time like `queue.wait(1000)`, or wake consumer thread explicitly calling `queue.notify()`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the queue is empty and since you have shutdown you never send anything into the queue to cause it to wake up.

Fix this either by sending a dummy message to the queue after setting the shutdown flag or by just removing the shutdown flag completely and sending a shutdown command to the queue.

Also be aware that if your shutdown flag is not `volatile` (or `AtomicBoolean`) then one thread may not see it being set by the other due to caching inside the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) is for:

```
    BlockingQueue queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(5);
    // ...
    while (!isShutdown()) {
        Object poll = queue.poll(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

Comment: This will solve the problem, but BlockingQueue offers take() method with efficiency benefits, Using poll() makes OP to use another implementation, Ryt?

Comment: @Nilesh - `take` will wait until something is put into the queue or an `interrupt` occurs. If the queue becomes empty and no further items are pushed onto it a `take` must be aborted destructively. Using `poll` allows us to also check for other states while waiting.

Answer (score 0):

you should change the design as advised above, or if you don't want to change your code, change your setShutdown() method body and statement to notify the queue.

```
public void setShutdown(boolean shutdown) {
  this.shutdown = shutdown;
  this.queue.notifyAll();
}
```

Comment: I got the following error when I tried to notifyAll during the shutdown process:

Dec 09, 2015 10:33:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: Servlet HttpEmailArrivedNotifyPL threw unload() exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.destroy() for servlet HttpEmailArrivedNotifyPL threw exception

Comment: Sorry my fault, notify and waits should be wrapped into synchronized block.